# String Table RGB values

Tags: c++

I am using a string table in my project and I want to store RGB values in it.  how do I convert rgb value from LoadString char to something that can be used for COLORREF for CreateSolidBrush.

Comment: do you need convert string to integer?

Comment: yes, something  like clrbuffer = "RGB(255,255,255)" converted for use with CreateSolidBrush (clrbuffer). Except "RGB(255, 255,255)" would be integer value instead of string

Comment: Something's not quite clear. Where are these strings coming from, are you free to choose the format that is easiest to convert?

Comment: Strings are coming from string table resource and would be used via LoadString(g_hInstance,IDS_STRING150,clrBuffer,...); clrBuffer is where I run into trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out using:

```
                    LoadString(g_hInstance,IDS_STRING151,rBuffer,256);
                    LoadString(g_hInstance,IDS_STRING152,gBuffer,256);
                    LoadString(g_hInstance,IDS_STRING153,bBuffer,256);
                    int r,g,b;
                    if(EOF == sscanf_s(rBuffer, "%d", &r))
                    {
                      //error
                    }
                    if(EOF == sscanf_s(gBuffer, "%d", &g))
                    {
                      //error
                    }
                    if(EOF == sscanf_s(bBuffer, "%d", &b))
                    {
                      //error
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN `COLORREF` is a `DWORD` typedef. So `COLORREF cRef = RGB( 0, 0, 0 );`is also valid. What I've understood you're trying to is something like:

```
const char *szTable[] = { "RGB( 255, 255, 255)", "RGB( 255, 0, 255)" }; //etc
COLORREF dwMyColor = szTable[0];
```

Getting a `COLORREF` object from a string table. I'm my opinion this is what you should do instead of string table:

```
COLORREF dwColor1 = RGB( 255, 0, 255 );
COLORREF dwTable[] = { 0xff00ff00, 0xffffffff, dwColor1 };
```

Why do you NEED a string table to store RGB values anyway? It wasn't clear enough I guess

Comment: just a project I am working on that requires me to use a string table instead of simpy using CreateSolidBrush (RGB(255,255,255));